# Segfaults and "Read-only filesystem" after a dist-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, segmentation-fault, io

After running an apt-get dist-upgrade on my 14.04 home server, it seems like something may have gone wrong which has left the box unusable.

It all started with this:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic_3.13.0-45.74_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic (3.13.0-45.74) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic_3.13.0-45.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic (3.13.0-45.74) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic_3.13.0-45.74_amd64.deb (--unpack): cannot copy extracted data for 
'./lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/sound/pci/echoaudio/snd-darla24.ko' to '/lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/sound/pci/echoaudio/snd-darla24.ko.dpkg-new': failed to write (Read-only file system)

dpkg: error while cleaning up:

unable to remove newly-extracted version of `/lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/sound/pci/echoaudio/snd-darla24.ko': Read-only file system
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
unable to remove newly-extracted version of `/lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/sound/pci/echoaudio/snd-indigoio.ko': Read-only file system

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 unable to remove newly-extracted version of `/lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/sound/pci/echoaudio/snd-indigodj.ko': Read-only file system
```

Followed by hundreds more similar lines about being unable to remove blah due to read-only file system.

For avoidance of doubt, the system wasn't read only before I ran the upgrade! In fact, I ran a standard apt-get upgrade just minutes before which completed without a problem.

First thing I tried to check fstab, but every attempt at opening the file with sudo have given me a segmentation fault.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/fstab
Segmentation fault
```

From here, I tried to open the files as a standard user, and am getting i/o errors:

```
$ vi /etc/fstab
-bash: /usr/bin/vi: Input/output error
```

I'm not really sure what to do at this point - I can still SSH into the box, but can't open any files, so I'm not sure what to check.  I'll have physical access in the next few hours, so am trying to get my head round whether the installation can be saved, or whether it's completely borked.

Has anyone come across anything like this before?  Any suggestions would be appreciated, and if you need any more info let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this question, it seems the underlying problem was I'd run out of disk space part way through a kernel update, so the initrd image file hadn't been created.  So as soon as I tried restarting, all I got was a kernel panic error.

To fix:

- Burned a copy of Xubuntu to a USB
- Booted to the USB and chose the "Try Xubuntu" option
- Opened terminal - found something I didn't need and deleted it (in my case, I had 3GB of Docker files sat in /var/lib/docker that were easily replaceable
- cd into /boot and make a note of the last working Kernel (for me, it was 3.13.0.43)
- Restarted - selected Advanced Boot Options (or whatever) at the GRUB menu and selected the kernel above
- System boots as normal (yay!) - ran sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
- Let Ubuntu do it's thing
- Reboot again as normal
- Fixed!

There may have been something on screen about having to run a dpkg command before I could upgrade, because of the previous botched update - I'm quoting a lot of this from memory.  Either way, I recall just running exactly what it told me to and all was good.

So yeah. Moral of the story - don't underestimate how big you may need your / partition to be, and keep an eye on disk space!